# Expected value and distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

I'm reading a book at the moment and it has a theorem that states this:

*if* $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ *then*
$E(X) = \mu$

My question is, when would it not equal $\mu$
I thought the expected value is the mean of any distribution, not just the normal.
Is this rule onle the case for the normal distribution, all symmetric distributions or all distributions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected value $ E(X) = \mu$ is often connected to the parameters of the distribution for instance

$$ X \sim Bin(n,p), E(X) = np$$

$$ X \sim Geom(p) , E(X) = p $$

$$  X \sim NegBin(r,p) , E(X) = \frac{r}{p}$$
$$ X \sim  Pois(\lambda) , E(X) = \lambda $$
$$  X \sim  N(\mu, \sigma^{2}) , E(X) = \mu $$
$$ X \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta) ,E(X) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$
$$ X \sim U(a,b) ,E(X) = \frac{b+a}{2} $$

$$ X \sim Beta(\alpha,\beta) ,E(X) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta} $$

So $ E(X) = \mu$ is a function of them simply because of how the expected value is defined..

$$ E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) dx$$

where $f(x)  $ is our density function, for continous functions

for discrete random variables we have
$$ E(X) = \sum_{i} x p(x_{i}) $$

It isn't surprising why we get the parameters of the distribution in our expectation because of this. For instance. Supppose $ X \sim U(a,b) $. It's pdf is given by.

$$ f(x) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a} &  \textrm{ for  } a \leq x \leq b \\ \\ 0  &  \textrm{ for  } x <a\textrm{ or } x >b \end{cases} \end{align}$$

$$ E(X)  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{1}{b-a}dx $$

$$ E(X)  = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx $$
$$ E(X)  = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} x dx $$
$$ E(X)  = \frac{1}{b-a} \frac{x^{2}}{2}\Big|_{a}^{b}$$
$$ E(X)  = \frac{1}{2(b-a)} b^{2}-a^{2}$$
$$ E(X)  = \frac{1}{2(b-a)} (b-a)(b+a)$$
$$ E(X)  = \frac{b+a}{2} $$

Comment: Yes, i'm understanding more now thanks to both of you. Thankyou.

Comment: Youre welcome, no problem

Answer (score 1):

The normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a probability distribution based on the pdf:

$f(x; \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Nowhere in that definition is it guaranteed that $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution, or that $\sigma$ is its standard deviation. Both need to be proven.

With other probability distributions, there's no guarantee that they will be directly parameterised by their expected value. For example, the log-normal distribution $\text{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ has an expected value of $e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$.

Comment: I think i'm understanding what you're saying @ConMan.  You're saying that we will use $E(X)$ to be our estimate of the population parameter $\mu$ and we will do the same for $var(X)$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: No, I'm saying that the probability distribution is defined by a function, which takes two parameters. The first parameter *happens* to be the expected value of the distribution, and the second one *happens* to be its variance. Similarly, the uniform distribution is parameterised by the start and end points, and its expected value is the average of the two.

Comment: And so I'm clear, neither of these are estimates. They are provably equal to the required values.

Comment: Oh  yeah I get it now, the parameters of a distribution aren't necessarily the average and the variance. They just happen to be the parameters for the normal distribution. So that would probably be the case for any symmetric distribution too? For example, $x^2, -1 < x < 1$?

Comment: That last question probably doesn't make sense probably, given my little knowledge of this topic, but if a distribution was symmetric, say in the shape of a parabola, i'm thinking the parameters would be the mean and variance again would it?

Comment: Nope, not necessarily. Like I said, the uniform distribution $U(a, b)$ is a flat line between the points $a$ and $b$. Its mean value is at $\frac{a+b}{2}$, and it's symmetric about that point. Parameters are just "the values necessary to define the shape of the distribution", and they do different things in different distributions.

Comment: oh yes of course. Thanks for your help @ConMan